# I am trying to take a vector of numbers 5:0 and repeat it 3 times, every other time reversing its order

Tags: r

I'd think this would be simple using the `rev()` and `seq()` functions, but am struggling to get the reverse order part correct.

I'm trying to get 5432101234543210 from 5:0.

Comment: `c(5:0, 1:4, 5:0)` seems easy enough. You could do `c(rev(seq(0, 5)), seq(1, 4), rev(seq(0, 5)))` if you want to complicate it with `rev` and `seq`.

Comment: Note that if you were really repeating 5:0 three times you you have 18 elements in the output, 543210012345543210.

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard to set as a function...

```
try_it <- function(x) {

  c(rev(x), x[2:length(x-1)], rev(x)[2:length(x-1)])

}

try_it(0:5)

# [1] 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

#### Edit

Extend function to have variable repeats

```
try_it <- function(x, reps) {

  c(rev(x), rep(c(x[2:length(x-1)], rev(x)[2:length(x-1)]), (reps - 1) / 2))

}

try_it(0:5, 5)

# [1] 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

*Note: I've not worked hard to generalise this extension, it will not return the correct length for an even number of repetitions. I'm sure you could modify to suit your requirements.*

Comment: Thanks so much! This actually similar to what I'd originally had-- any clue how it might "scale" beyond three repeats of the vector 5:0? It repeats that sequence thrice here, could I write this in such a way I could change a variable from 3 to 5, and it could repeat 5 times? 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0